# Qcircuit: How to insert a vertical dashed line in a circuit?

Tags: xy-pic

I want to insert vertical dashed lines between parts of the following circuit to make some comments:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[matrix,frame,arrow]{xy}
\input{Qcircuit}
\vfuzz2pt % Don't report over-full v-boxes if over-edge is small
\begin{document}
\[
    \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
     \lstick{\ket{x}} & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \rstick{\ket{x}} \qw \\
     \lstick{\ket{y}} & \gate{H} & \gate{\pi} & \gate{H} & \rstick{\ket{y \oplus x}} \qw
    }
\]
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

I have found a similar question ([xypic: How to typeset the dashed line in this diagram?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97433/xypic-how-to-typeset-the-dashed-line-in-this-diagram) ) concerning xy-pic, it is the same idea, it should be the same solution. But it's not working, I don't know why.

Note: [Q-circuit](http://www.cquic.org/Qcircuit/Qtutorial.pdf) is a [`Qcircuit.tex` macro package](http://www.cquic.org/Qcircuit/Qcircuit.tex) for drawing quantum circuit diagrams in LaTeX

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Can you give an idea/sketch inside Q where the dotted line should be or do you need a box encompassing the `[H]` ?. The answers to your linked Q will work if you remove the `\input{Qcircuit}` macro which is specifically defined for `\Qcircuit`. Those answers need only pure xy-pic `\usepackage[all]{xy}`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example placement.  I have used a dotted rather than dashed line for clarity.  To get dashes use `\ar@{--}` instead of `\ar@{.}`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{Qcircuit}

\begin{document}

\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
 \lstick{\ket{x}} & \qw \ar@{.}[]+<3.5em,1em>;[d]+<3.5em,-1em>
 & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \rstick{\ket{x}} \qw \\
 \lstick{\ket{y}} & \gate{H} & \gate{\pi} & \gate{H} & \rstick{\ket{y \oplus x}} \qw
}
\end{document}
```

The command used was:

```
\ar@{.}[]+<3.5em,1em>;[d]+<3.5em,-1em>
```

placed at the node where you want the line to start.  The `[d]` points to the node one line down, `[dd]` would send you two lines down instead, `[r]` would make the line go to the right.  The `<3.5em,1em>` means the line starts `3.5em` to the right and `1em` above the starting node.  Similarly `<3.5em,-1em>` puts the end `3.5em` to the right and `1em` below the end node.

Comment: It works but a problem happens when include `\usepackage[francais]{babel}`and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, the line is not vertical and a part of the command is displayed in the output file!

Comment: That is because `;` is a shorthand in that set-up.  Use a `\shorthandoff{;}` as e.g. `\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em { \shorthandoff{;}...`, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86025/15925